# Symfony2, relation manyToMany in a Form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony-forms

I start learning sf2, pretty cool, for my problem I have two tables:

**Media**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Test\SiteBundle\Entity\Website", inversedBy="medias")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="media_website")

private $websites;
```

and **Website**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Test\SiteBundle\Entity\Media", mappedBy="websites")

private $medias;
```

In my MediaType.php I have this:

```
$builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('website', 'entity', array(
            'class'         =>  'TestSiteBundle:Website',
            'property'  =>  'name',
            'query_builder' => function(WebsiteRepository $er)use($user_id) {
                               return $er->getMyWebsites($user_id);
             },
            'multiple'=>false))
```

finally, in the twig page I have this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   {{ form_label(form.description, "Description", { 'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label col-md-2'} }) }}
   <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ form_widget(form.description, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
   </div>
</div>
```

When I try to add a Media I have this error:

```
Neither the property "websites" nor one of the methods "setWebsites()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Test\SiteBundle\Entity\Media".
```

Any help ? and many thanks to you.

Answer (score 5):

I found it, for persons who have the same problem, in the relation ManyToMany you need to have **multiple=>true** in your FormType, so my MediaType should be:

```
$builder

        ->add('websites', 'entity', array(
            'class'         =>  'EveadSiteBundle:Website',
            'property'  =>  'name',
            'query_builder' => function(WebsiteRepository $er)use($user_id) {
                               return $er->getMyWebsites($user_id);
             },
            'multiple'=>true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the properties on both classes to `protected` rather than `private` to allow doctrine to access them in its Proxy classes.

You'll also need to add public getter and setter methods in order to access the data on your models in your application. You can use the Symfony Console's `doctrine:generate:entities` command - [see documentation here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I changed the properties to protected, and I already have the getters and setters in the models: '  public function addWebsite(), public function removeWebsite(), public function getWebsites()'